# Pandas output different rows between two dataframes excluding certain keywords

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to track the difference between two dfs. However, for certain keywords, I don't want to compare a column. For example, tracking difference between quantity and price, while excluding "apple"

---

df1

```
    item    quantity    price
0   apple   3           3
1   pear    2           2
2   orange  1           1
```

---

df2

```
    item    quantity    price
0   apple   3           2
1   pear    2           1
2   orange  1           2
```

---

output df

```
    item    quantity    price
0   pear    2.0         1.0
1   orange  1.0         2.0
```

---

Comparing df2 against one df1 produces pear and orange, while apple is also different it is ignored.

Whats a good way to do this?

Comment: There are `df` and `df1` same number of rows and columns? So possible compare elementwise?

Answer (score 0):

Solution if possible compare elementwise - it means each values per rows:

```
df = df2[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1) & df1.item.ne('apple')]
print (df)
     item  quantity  price
1    pear         2      1
2  orange         1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

To first find the unique columns in both the dataframes, use `drop_duplicates(keep=False)`.

After that keep only those columns in df2 by removing the columns from df1.

And finally make a list of keywords and drop the rows where column is in keywords.

This can be implemented as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['apple',3,3],['pear',2,2],['orange',1,1]], columns = ['item','quantity','price'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['apple',3,2],['pear',2,1],['orange',1,2]], columns = ['item','quantity','price'])

#create df of unqiue cols from both df where common cols are dropped
df3 = (pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)).reset_index(drop=True)

#keep only the cols in df2
df3 = df3[~df3.isin(df1)].dropna()

#make list of keywords and drop rows where col isin keywords
keywords = ['apple']
df3[~df3['item'].isin(keywords)].reset_index(drop=True)

#this will output
    item    quantity    price
0   pear    2.0         1.0
1   orange  1.0         2.0
```